# Is there a way to control which URLs a cookie gets sent to?

Tags: .net, http, iis, cookies, web

My session cookie is somewhat long (about 700 bytes), since it contains various encrypted user information and what not.  There's some things I can do to get that size down, and I'm working on that angle too, but that's another topic.

My issue is that I don't like how this cookie gets sent to the server on every single HTTP request; including requests to JPG images, CSS files, and static Javascript files.  Since the cookie isn't needed on these requests, I feel it might slow down page load times since this is 700 bytes x the number of resources the page loads.  Obviously, these files get cached and what not but still I'd like my pages to load and quickly and smoothly as possible.

The one solution I can think of is to put all my static content on another sub-domain, such as `cdn.myserver.com/images/` and `cdn.myserver.com/scripts/`, and set the cookie-path to only include `www.myserver.com`.  I believe this would work, but it complicates dev and staging environments.  I'd probably end up having to generate URLs dynamically depending on what environment the code was being run in.

**My Question:**

Besides the solution above, is there any way to prevent cookies from being sent across the wire for certain HTTP requests, such as image, script and style resources?

I'm running on the .NET stack, with IIS7.5 as a web server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't anything you can do from a server perspective; by the time your server (IIS) or your framework (ASP.NET, or other) has received the request, the cookies have already been sent.

What you mentioned will absolutely work, quoting [RFC 2109 ("HTTP State Management Mechanism")](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2109.txt) (emphasis mine):

> Hosts names can be specified either as an IP address or a FQHN string.  Sometimes we compare one host name with another.  Host A's name domain-matches host B's if
>
> - both host names are IP addresses and their host name strings match exactly; or
> - both host names are FQDN strings and their host name strings match exactly; or
> - **A is a FQDN string and has the form NB, where N is a non-empty name string, B has the form .B', and B' is a FQDN string.  (So, x.y.com domain-matches .y.com but not y.com.)**
>
> Note that domain-match is not a commutative operation: **a.b.c.com domain-matches .c.com, but not the reverse.**

So creating a separate sub-domain, while specifically keying your cookies to a *different* sub-domain will work.

Note that it's [commonly accepted practice to do this in order to increase page speed](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#cookie_free) and [Stack Overflow has been doing this since late 2009](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/a-few-speed-improvements/).

In order to reduce the complexity of your staging and dev environments, I recommend following this lead; having the content on a separate domain means that you don't have to do anything different for any of those environments.

Comment: Yea, for images I think it'd be a no brainer to use a CDN.  For scripts, I'm constantly changing them and running the app in Visual Studio, and having to push script changes out to a CDN every time would be a hassle.  I'd have to code something that points to a local URL when running off `localhost` and the CDN when running in production.

Comment: @MikeChristensen It's a pain, definitely, but yeah, it's what needs to be done.  Can you differentiate on DEBUG or RELEASE builds?  You can use an `ifdef` in your function and return the appropriate URL.

Comment: Yea, it'll be some sort of `web.config` setting.  Resources referred to within script files I think will just magically work, as long as the script is on the same CDN as the resources it refers to.  Only URLs on the non-CDN resources will have to be fully qualified, and those can be generated by code.

Answer (score 1):

As I know the only solution is using the cookieless domain or sub-domain which you has mentioned.
but remember that domain or sub-domain should be Canonical DNS Name pointed to your main  domain.

For easing the development and staging environments, I recommend you to use [CombineAndMinify](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/125159/Package-that-speeds-up-loading-of-JavaScript-CSS-a) Component along with your ASP.net project, so it will fulfill your need in the background, and it also has some other features you may like to use them.
In addition it has debug|release mode, so you can bypass it when you are debugging.

Comment: `+1` for the CombineAndMinify rec, I'll check that out, or at least code something similar!

Comment: this component is wonderful and it's open-source, so as I did you may want to add or change some features to it. you just compile it, place the compiled .dll in your BIN, add some lines to your web.config and it's done. Good Luck